# MacBook Pro2018にLinuxをインストールして動かすことはできる?

Tags: linux, macbook

MacBook Pro 2018にLinuxを入れて動きますか?

ディストリビューションやLinux kernelのバージョンは問いません。
私はMacBook Pro 2018をまだ持っていません。
しかし、Linuxが動くかどうか非常に気になります。
実際はどうなのでしょうか?

いくつか、障害となりそうな点を考えてみました。

- Touch Bar (ドライバなどがないため動かなさそう。ファンクションキーが使えない?)
- バッテリの持ちやファンの動作 (熱の感知ができずファンがフルで回り続けたり、バッテリーの減りが早くなる?)
- T2チップのせいでそもそもインストールできない? (もしかしたら
  https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/HT208330
  の通りにsecure bootをオフにすればできるのかもしれないが...)

MacBook Pro2018でLinuxを動かすことはできるのでしょうか?

Comment: 直接インストールする前にUSBブートで試すという選択肢もあります。ネットで調べた範囲だとドライバ周りの問題で(現時点では)直接のインストールには複数の課題がありそうです。- 参考: [Install Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 on MacBook Pro 2018?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1052373), [Has any tried linux on 2018 MacBook Pro?](https://www.reddit.com/r/macbookpro/comments/92690u/has_any_tried_linux_on_2018_macbook_pro/)

Comment: なるほどまだまだ大変そうですね…… https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/71

Answer (score 1):

Linuxに何を求めているかに依ると思います

そもそもmacOSは、BSD系のunixの派生として作られたOSなので、

- `POSIX`準拠コマンドが使えて欲しいだけならTerminalを開くだけで良い
- フリーウェアが動いて欲しいなら、`MacPorts`や`HomeBrew`などのパッケージマネージャーもあります
- `Guest OS`としてLinuxを動かしたいのであれば、`Virtual Box`という手段も有ります
- `XWindow`でウィンドウ環境を構築したいなら`XQuartz`が使えます

上記よりもっとLinuxとして動いて欲しい（別なサーバーの立ち上げ実験マシンなど）のであれば話は別ですが
MacBook Pro (2018)に0からLinuxを導入するメリットはほとんどなく、
MacOSのCUIレイヤーを使えば大抵のことは出来てしまうと思います
`macOS`を介さないLinuxをどうしてもインストールしたいのでしょうか？

Comment: `macOSを介さないLinuxをどうしてもインストールしたいのでしょうか？`
はい、その通りです。
どうしてもLinuxマシン(仮想でない)が必要なのですが、iOS開発もしたいのです。

Comment: 了解です。それだとTouchBarのドライバーなどに不安があるので中古のWindowsマシンやMac miniをLinuxサーバーにして、MacBook ProはそのLinuxマシンへのクライアントにするのが良い様な気がします。そうすれば、Linuxへクライアント接続したときの実験も出来ますし、作業自体はMacBook Proから出来ますし。ありきたりな回答で済みませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

気になって ググってみましたが MBP2018 でLinuxが動くという報告は見つかりませんでした。

MBP2016/2017 についてはドキュメントがありましたので ご参考にしてください。
https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7

方針としては、動作確認が取れる古いモデルを入手するか、ダメ元でやってみるか、動作報告が上がるのを待つしか無いと思います。